# Share data from .gs (Google Apps Script) to <script> variable in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
[
  {"id":1,"label":"Node 2"},
  {"id":2,"label":"Node 3"},
  {"id":3,"label":"Node 4"},
  {"id":4,"label":"Node 5"}
]
```

Hi! In the following code, the function **getArray()** returns this string ↑. Do you know how to connect it with the variable **nodes** in the .html . I pasted the codes, Thanks!

```
function getArray(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const data = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

  let objArray = []
  data.forEach(element => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.id = element[0]
    obj.label = element[1]
    objArray.push(obj)
    return element
    }
  )
var obj = JSON.stringify(objArray);
//Logger.log(obj);
return obj;
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var nodes = [
  {"id":1,"label":"Node 2"},
  {"id":2,"label":"Node 3"},
  {"id":3,"label":"Node 4"},
  {"id":4,"label":"Node 5"}
];

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Recap: My goal is use the returned "obj" in .gs as var "nodes" in .html. I don't know if the programming speech its correct. Thanks!

If some can share me the code, im going to thanks you a lot thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about modifying `var nodes = [...]` to `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes => console.log(nodes)).getArray()` in HTML side? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Doesn't work . My goal is use the returned "obj" in .gs as var "nodes" in .html. I don't know if the programming language its correct. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation from `Doesn't work`. And I cannot understand about `use the returned "obj" in .gs as var "nodes" in .html`. Because `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes => console.log(nodes)).getArray()` brings the values from returned from `getArray()` to HTML side. So can you provide the detail information for replicating `Doesn't work`? From this, I would like to try to understand about your goal.

Comment: If you want to merge content into HTML when the HTML ***loads***, then you can use Templated HTML with scriptlets.  If you want to retrieve data ***after*** the HTML has loaded, and inject content you'll need to use `google.script.run.withSuccessHander(fncNameToHandleReturn).fncNameHere()` and then use JavaScript and the DOM to manipulate the HTML in the browser.  Do you want the content to be merged when the HTML first loads, or at some point afterwards?

Comment: I saw your whole script in your shared Spreadsheet. Can you show the script in your question? By this, users can see your whole script. By the way, in your case, `nodes` is required to be used as an object. So I think that `return objArray` is used instead of `return obj` in `getArray()`. By this, I think that `nodes` returned by `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes => console.log(nodes)).getArray()` can be used for your script. How about this?

Comment: I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? In this case, I used `google.script.run`. If that was not the direction you wnat, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- In this answer, the value of `nodes` are retrieved by `google.script.run`.
- At `getArray()` in GAS side, the value is returned as an object.
- At JavaScript side, the object of `nodes` is used for vis.js.

### Modified script

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function showBox() {
   var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Map");
   var html = template.evaluate();
   html.setHeight(450).setWidth(650);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "New Title");
}

function getArray(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const data = ss.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  
  let objArray = []
  data.forEach(element => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.id = element[0]
    obj.label = element[1]
    objArray.push(obj)
    return element
    }
  )
  return objArray;  // Modified
}
```

#### HTML and Javascript side:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #mynetwork {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Modified
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes => {
  var edges = [{from: 1, to: 3}, {from: 1, to: 2}, {from: 2, to: 4}, {from: 2, to: 5}, {from: 3, to: 3}];
  var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
  var data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};
  var options = {edges: {smooth: false}, physics: {enabled: false}};
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
}).getArray();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: You are great! Thanks a lot, and no problem with share the result!

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: sorry, can you help me with another related thing? Do you know how can i do the same thing but now with the edges?. At this time im create a new `function getArray()` but now for the edges. The point now its to remplace the `var edges = [{from: 1, to: 3}, {from: 1, to: 2}, {from: 2, to: 4}, {from: 2, to: 5}, {from: 3, to: 3}];` Thanks!

Comment: @Mario IR I have to apologize for my poor English skill.  Unfortunate, about your new question, I couldn't understand about what you want to do and your new issue. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about `getEdgesArray()`, as a simple method, if `getEdgesArray()` is Google Apps Script side, how about calling `getEdgesArray()` in the function of `getArray()` and returning both values to Javascript side?

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current issue from `dont work`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was resolved.

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. If your posted answer is not the answer, please delete it. Because that is not the answer for your this question. If you want to post it, please post it as new question. By this, we can answer for your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. At that time, can you include more information? By this, it will help to think of the solution.

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for your response.