# Replace a var with google.script.run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, vis.js, vis.js-network

Im very basic in js and i have an little issue with the following code.

How can i relate the `var edges = [{from: 1, to: 3}, {from: 1, to: 2}, {from: 2, to: 4}, {from: 2, to: 5}, {from: 3, to: 3}];` (in the HTML and Javacript Side) with a kind of `getArray()` (in the Google Script Side), to get the similar result of this post [Share data from .gs (Google Apps Script) to <script> variable in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841067/share-data-from-gs-google-apps-script-to-script-variable-in-html) but, with the "edges" instead the "nodes"?

It can be `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes, edges => {...}).coneArray().edgeArray();`?

**Google Script Side**

```
function showBox() {
   var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Map");
   var html = template.evaluate();
   html.setHeight(450).setWidth(650);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, "Mind Map");
}

function include() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile().getContent();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------Global variables

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------Nodes function

function coneArray(){
  
  const data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues();

  let nodeArray = []
  
  data.forEach(element => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.id = element[4]
    obj.label = element[0]
    obj.group = element[1]
    obj.x = element[2]
    obj.y = element[3]
    nodeArray.push(obj)
    return element
    }
  )
  Logger.log(nodeArray);
  return nodeArray;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------Edges function

function lineArray(){
  
  const data = ss.getRange(2,5,ss.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

  let edgArray = []
  
  data.forEach(element => {
    let obj = {}
    obj.to = element[1]
    obj.from = element[0]
    edgArray.push(obj)
    return element
    }
  )
  Logger.log(edgArray);
  return edgArray;
}
```

**HTML and Javacript Side**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Network</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #mynetwork {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Reload" onclick="google.script.run.showBox()" />
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var options = {edges: {smooth: false}, physics: {enabled: false}, nodes: {shape: "square",size: 10}};

var edges = [{from: 1, to: 3}, {from: 1, to: 2}, {from: 2, to: 4}, {from: 2, to: 5}, {from: 3, to: 3}];

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes => {
  var data = {nodes: nodes, edges: edges};
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
}).coneArray();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Before hand, thanks a lot!

> PS: The goal is connect the nodes with the edges data in a google spreadsheets.
>
> PS: I share the entire code because, will not have sense in a part.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your case, how about calling both functions in one function at GAS side? In this case, I think that your goal can be achieved by one call of `google.script.run`. How about this?

Comment: I dont know how to do that :/ if you can explain me, i will thanks you a lot. Also i can share you the google sheets again [Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ri10uXw94DSDRy8vXcs6OqkNzaZ49aIiJYiAH8RMEoA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your situation, there are 2 functions of `coneArray()` and `edgeArray()` in Google Apps Script. You want to retrieve the values from both functions and using the values, you want to use vis.js.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

In this modification, the values are retrieved both `coneArray()` and `edgeArray()`, and the retrieved values are used for vis.js.

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following script to the Google Apps Script.

```
const sample = () => ([coneArray(), edgeArray()]);
```

#### HTML and Javascript side:

Please replace your script of `google.script.run` to as follows.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodes, edges: edges}, options)).sample();
```

#### Note:

- If you want to call each function from Javascript, you can also use the following Javascript as a simple script. But I would like to recommend above modified script.

  ```
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(edges => {
      new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodes, edges: edges}, options)
    }).edgeArray();
  }).coneArray();
  ```

Comment: It does not work. Is it more practical for to edit directly the code in the [Google Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ri10uXw94DSDRy8vXcs6OqkNzaZ49aIiJYiAH8RMEoA/edit#gid=0)? Feel free to share the entire code if you want. Thanks again!

Comment: PS: If you want to test the code just init the `showBox()`, and see the result in the Google Spreadsheets. Thanks!

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your question, `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nodes, edges => {...}).coneArray().edgeArray();` is used. So I proposed `const sample = () => ([coneArray(), edgeArray()]);`. But when I saw the script of your shared Spreadsheet, I could confirm that there are 2 functions `coneArray()` and `lineArray()` for sending values. It seems that your question is different from your shared Spreadsheet. How about this? In this case, how about `const sample = () => ([coneArray(), lineArray()]);`?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to share the `lineArray()` part of the GS because it is a test it does not worked. I edited the main question. If you have a better idea to receive the values of the range E2:F in the [Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ri10uXw94DSDRy8vXcs6OqkNzaZ49aIiJYiAH8RMEoA/edit#gid=0) and use it instead of the `var edges = [...];` feel free to edit the code and share it here. Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm about your current situation. Because unfortunately, from `it does not worked`, I cannot understand about your current situation. I deeply apologize for this. Your current script for replicating your current issue is included in the shared Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, i edited the code to be the same as the [Spreadsheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ri10uXw94DSDRy8vXcs6OqkNzaZ49aIiJYiAH8RMEoA/edit#gid=0)

Comment: PS: You can check the code executing the `showBox()` and watching the SpreadSheets. If the nodes are connected among themselfs, its means the code does work.

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. When I saw your current script in the shared Spreadsheet, I could understand that my answer is not reflected to your script. Can you reflect my answer for your script and test it again? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about `it does not worked`.

Comment: No problem, im going to try it, 1. in wich line of the **Google Script Side** i must paste the `const sample = () => ([coneArray(), edgeArray()]);`?                                   2. In wich line of the **HTML and Javascript side** i must paste the `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([nodes, edges]) => new vis.Network(container, {nodes: nodes, edges: edges}, options)).sample();`?

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that the proposal of my comment was not used. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you modify `const sample = () => ([coneArray(), edgeArray()]);` to `const sample = () => ([coneArray(), lineArray()]);` and test it again? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843668/replace-a-var-with-google-script-run#comment107648373_60843777)

Comment: It works now! man your aweosome. Sorry for the issues and thanks for the patience! Now i can use it as a mind map!

Comment: @Mario IR Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.